# Comparing vs Comparison

Tags: word-choice

Could you please enlighten my classmates and me which one is the correct wording of the sentence?

> We make comparison easy so you can decide quickly and feel confident you have found the best deal.

vs

> We make comparing easy so you can decide quickly and feel confident you have found the best deal.

Comment: This is a good question, but you should add more detail to explain what you think may be correct, and why, and what research or source material you have checked.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are grammatically correct and have the same meaning.

The grammartical form:

> To make + `nominalized verb` / `verb-ing` + adjective

This should work if *the same verb* is either *nominalized* or *gets an "ing"*.

Examples:

> This tool makes *cutting* easy. 
>  (can't nominalize "to cut" as "a cut")
>
> That machine makes *printing* faster. 
>  (can nominalize "to print" as "print jobs")
>
> Her program made *shopping* more convenient. 
>  (can't nominalize "to shop")
>
> His invention made *trash collection/collecting* easier.
>
> The system makes *production* more eco-friendly.
>  ("producing" can be used, but it usually goes with a noun pointing out the product e.g. *makes producing paper more eco-friendly*)
>
> These machines make *construction/constructing* safer. 
>  
>   (using "construction" often sounds better and *a bit* more general)

Comment: I agree with your examples, but your answer says they have the same meaning.  To improve your answer, could you add some more detail?  If they are **truly the same**, would you say "These machines make constructing safer"?

Comment: OK I edited to clarify the examples. Note that some verbs *can't* be nomalized so we just use the *"V-ing"* form.

Comment: I am not the asker but this is a very helpful answer. Thank you.